# Can microneedling damage the buccal nerve if your skin is thin?

Tags: face, plastic-surgery

I have an atrophic scar about 4cm to the right of my lip. I wanted to get subcision but the plastic surgeon said there's a risk of damaging the buccal nerve which would then mean I wouldn't be able to speak properly. 
He said it's risky because I don't have much collagen in that area.

1) How deep is the dermis and epidermis in that region?
2) is the Buccal nerve right below the epidermis or is it protected by a muscle or another layer?
3) How deep would you need to go to hit the buccal nerve?
4) Would a dermapen that goes 2.5mm deep hit the buccal nerve if the skin in that area is not very thick due to collagen loss?

Comment: +0. Question is not understandable by the lay public: it's only understandable by medical professionals. Please dejargonify.